# Run NUnit 2.5.5 tests in Gallio 3.1

Tags: nunit, gallio

I'm trying to get Gallio running some existing NUnit tests but they're not showing in Gallio.  The assembly loads into Gallio fine and I can run them fine via Resharper within the VS IDE.

I created a really simple NUnit test in VS and this also doesn't show so I know it's not something weird in my existing tests.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version of Gallio (3.1 build 397) only supports NUnit up to 2.5.2.

But if you drop in the new 2.5.5 assemblies into C:\Program Files (x86)\Gallio\bin\NUnit\v2.5 and update Gallio.NUnitAdapter25.plugin with the new version numbers you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

As Carl said, Gallio v3.1 only supports NUnit up to v2.5.2. I suggest you use Gallio v3.2 instead. It's still in beta but is very stable already. You may want to try the [latest daily build](http://ccnet.gallio.org/Distributables/).

UPDATE1: [Gallio v3.2 now RC](http://interfacingreality.blogspot.com/2010/07/gallio-mbunit-32-rc.html)
UPDATE2: There is breaking change in the test model of NUnit v2.5.4. The Gallio NUnit adapter has been updated accordingly. You might want to use Gallio 3.2 [build 520](http://ccnet.gallio.org/Distributables/) or later.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark--are your text fixtures public?

Comment: They are yes.  Sorry might fault, I should have said they appear and run fine in the NUnit runner.